# SyntaxError comparing a date with a field in Python

Tags: python, pandas

Q) Resample the data to get prices for the end of the business month. Select the Adjusted Close for each stock.import pandas as pd

```
mmm = pd.read_csv('mmm.csv')
ibm = pd.read_csv('ibm.csv')
fb = pd.read_csv('fb.csv')

amz_date = amz.loc['Date']==2017-6-30 #dataframe showing enitire row for that date
amz_price = amz_date[:, ['Date', 'AdjClose']]  #dataframe with only these 2 columns

mmm_date = mmm.loc['Date']==2017-6-30 #dataframe showing enitire row for that date
mmm_price = mmm_date[:, ['Date', 'AdjClose']]

ibm_date = ibm.loc['Date']==2017-6-30 #dataframe showing enitire row for that date
ibm_price = ibm_date[:, ['Date', 'AdjClose']]

fb_date = fb.loc['Date']==2017-6-30 #dataframe showing enitire row for that date
fb_price = fb_date[:, ['Date', 'AdjClose']]
```

```
KeyError: 'Date'
```

What Am i doing wrong? also Date is column in csv file

Comment: Please try to make your title describe enough of your problem that once it's answered, someone with a similar problem will be able to tell if your answers are likely to help them just by looking at the title. Right now this same title applies to almost *any* Python question.

Comment: One immediate problem is that `2017-06-30` is not a legal way to describe a date in Python. Instead, it's a subtraction operation that evaluates to `1981` (2017 - 6 - 30 == 1981, because 1981 + 6 == 1987, and 1987 + 30 == 2017).

Comment: That is to say, put quotes around it to make it a string.

Comment: ...if the dataframe is storing strings rather than Python datetime objects. I don't know how smart the pandas CSV reader tries to be.

Comment: Also, you are evaluating whether a Series is equal to one single date, which is certainly not true.

Answer (score 1):

Your *particular* problem is that "06" is not a legal way to describe a value here.  To do arithmetic, you'd need to drop the leading zero.

Your next problem is that 2017-06-30 is (would be) an arithmetic expression that evaluates to the integer 1981.  You need to express this as a date, such as `datetime.strptime("6-30-2017")`.

Comment: This is true, but I'm not sure it's the only problem here. Why would this result in a SyntaxError, instead of just assigning `False` to `amz_date`?

Comment: Thanks for the reminder -- I went to look up integer formats and wandered off into the weeds.

Comment: Heh. TIL that python3 doesn't follow the leading-`0`-means-octal convention.

Comment: Thank you now i am getting this error KeyError: 'Date'. Date is the column in csv file. Please help. This is the question (Resample the data to get prices for the end of the business month. Select the Adjusted Close for each stock.)

Comment: That would be a separate question, requiring a new SO post.  Furthermore, your code posted for this question does not give the information critical to solving your new problem.